# The Internal RMI Registry port 1099 may be in use by another application Nokia SDK

Tags: nokia-n8

I am getting an error:

```
The Internal RMI Registry port 1099 may be in use by another application.
```

I change it to a different port, but I still get the error.  I am using windows 7, 64 bit and Nokia SDK1.1.

Answer (score 9):

Java 7 u21 (and Java 6 u45) reintroduced this problem. Nokia SDK works with Java 7 u17 (and Java 6 u43).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the port, killed all other java apps, but no luck.

In the end, the problem turned out to be a jdk/jre bug. Apparently, the bug surfaced since 1.6 u 29. Here is the bug report. in sdk release note. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u27-download-440405.html

So switching to older JDK should fix the problem. I uninstalled jdk and installed JDK1.6 update 23 and it's working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

The JDKv1.6u30 fixed this bug.